# Poor scrolling performance in MAUI list view on mac platfrom

Tags: maui

I have a simple listview sample and load Grid with some labels as an item template to the listview. I have faced a poor scrolling performance in the MAUI ListView when scrolling it in the initial loading. The first time an item is added to the ListView, it affects the scrolling performance.

The main page contains the following codes,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:app="clr-namespace:SimpleMauiApp"
             x:Class="SimpleMauiApp.MainPage">

    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <app:ViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

You can find the entire sample from [this](https://github.com/ashok-kuvaraja/ListViewMauiSample/tree/main/SimpleMauiApp) link,

Comment: Why aren't you using a CollectionView?

Comment: set a fixed height request to HorizontalStackLayout, looking at those fixed labels set a fixed widthrequest to stack too too

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to improve the scrolling performance when loading multiple items in a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.listview?view=net-maui-7.0), you may need change the [CachingStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview#cache-data) to `RecycleElement`:

- `RecycleElement`, specifies that the [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.listview?view=net-maui-7.0) will attempt to minimize
  its memory footprint and execution speed by recycling list cells.

And also you can refer to [ListView performance suggestions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#listview-performance-suggestions) which applies to MAUI.

In addition, you might use `CollectionView` rather than `ListView` as the former one is a preferable control moving forward with a better performance. Since the items of the `CollectionView` have the exact same height, setting [ItemSizingStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout#item-sizing) to `MeasureFirstItem` strategy will result in increased performance when used in situations where the item size is intended to be uniform across all items.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem" > 
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <Label WidthRequest="100" Text="{Binding}" />
                          ...
                        <!--Omitted for Brevity>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```